# Azure AKS External Load Balancer Not Connecting to POD

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am trying to create a multicontainer pod for a simple demo. I have an app that is build in docker containers. There are 3 containers

1 - redis server
1 - node/express microservice
2 - node/express/react front end

All 3 containers are deployed successfully and running.
I have created a public load balancer, which is running without any errors.

I cannot connect to the front end from the public ip.

I have also run tcpdump in the frontend container and there is no traffic getting in.

Here is my yaml file used to create the deployment and service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mydemoapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mydemoapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mydemoapp
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: microservices-web
        image: mydemocr.azurecr.io/microservices_web:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3001
      - name: redislabs-rejson
        image: mydemocr.azurecr.io/redislabs-rejson:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
      - name: mydemoappwebtest
        image: mydemocr.azurecr.io/jsonformwebtest:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mydemoappservice
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: mydemoapp
```

This is what a describe of my service looks like :

```
Name:                     mydemoappservice
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"mydemoappservice","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"p...
Selector:                 app=mydemoapp
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.0.104.159
LoadBalancer Ingress:     20.49.172.10
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               3000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31990/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.17:3000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  24m   service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   24m   service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

One more weirdness is that when I run the docker container from the front end I can get a shell and run `curl localhost:3000` and get some output but when I do it in the az container I get the following response after some delay

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

As to why this container works on my machine and not in azure is another layer to the mystery.

Comment: Is your container listening on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: I don't believe so. const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {

})

Comment: Container need to listen on `0.0.0.0`. Can you try making change in your code to do so?

Comment: output of netstat tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      52/node

Comment: Are you able to `exec` into the same container and do `curl localhost:3000` or  `curl 127.0.0.1:3000`?

Comment: Yes that is what I was doing. It times out. If I run the image locally under docker and shell into it it works. I have changed the code to read app.list(port, '127.0.0.1', () =>{});. Netstat now reflects this. Still not working mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219860/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-charlie-benger-stevenson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring from docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#container-v1-core) the container need to listen on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` because

> any port which is listening on the default `0.0.0.0` address inside a
> container will be accessible from the network

.

Comment: Changed to both ip addresses and neither made a difference. Curl from a shell inside the container does not work when the container is running in Azure. Running TCPDUMP inside the container shows there is no traffic coming in from the LoadBalancer. Running the same image locally and getting a shell into the container and Curl works just fine.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you have a command for that? I ran kubectl get services and this is what I get mydemoappservice   LoadBalancer   10.0.104.159   20.49.172.10   80:31990/TCP   144m

Comment: I see you have 3 containers listening on different ports but in service you are only exposing port `3000` is that intentional? Are you exposing the right container?

Comment: I am exposing the correct container, and yes this is intentional. As its a demo only I just want the web app exposed to the world on port 80. This then cranks the microservice internally on localhost:3001 which in turn queries redis on localhost:6379

Comment: I added some debug code to my default route and it hit it so it's something weird going on with my app. I shall investigate further. No clue why nothing is not showing up in tcpdump. Then again I am running the app from the command line inside the container, maybe this makes a difference? My docker file uses CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ] to launch the dev script in the package.json. Running this has npm run dev from the CL in the aks container in a shell works.